# Add new context variables to lithium\template\view\adapter\File

Tags: php, lithium

I'd like to replicate the functionality of the `$this->head()` and `$this->scripts()` handlers to add `$this->footer()`. I understand that I can use `Renderer::handlers()` to register a new handler, but I'm not sure how I can extend the File::$_context property to add the new `footer` context.

So far, I assume I'd add the snippet below to an `Html` helper.

```
protected function _init() {
    parent::_init();

    if ($this->_context) {
        $ctx =& $this->_context;

        $this->_context->handlers(array(
            'footer' => function($footers) use (&$ctx) {
                    return "\n\t" . join("\n\t", $ctx['footer']) . "\n";
                }
        ));
    }
}
```

Perhaps I'm overthinking it, and should just extend my `Html` helper to replicate the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but with the way `__call()` works, you should be able to say `$this->_context += ['footer' => []]` inside `_init()` then call `$this->footer("Foo!")` to append.

When you're ready to render, `$this->context("footer")` should give you back an array of values.